# Redis count items in a geo index

Tags: redis

I added some records using GEOADD, but how can I get a count of how many items?

I made one called `cities` and added a bunch of city lat/lng, but I am curious how I can get a count of how many there are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geo index is, in fact, a sorted set. So you can use `ZCARD` to get the size of index.

Comment: Thx. Is there any resource you recommend for better understanding redis? The docs are fine but kind of go over my head a lot..